# Azure AD admin consent from the Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered few apps in Azure AD and these apps require admin consent. Can the tenant admin instead of opening each app and then providing consent, can he just select the apps in the azure portal and provide his consent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consent framework is used to make it easy to develop multi-tenant Web and Native client applications that need to access Web APIs secured by an Azure AD tenant, different from the one where the client application is registered.

Based on the test, if you were developing single-tenant apps, there is not necessary for admin to give consent. Here are two helpful articles about consent framework.

[Integrating applications with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/#comments)

[How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview/#understanding-user-and-admin-consent)

Comment: Thanks for the response Fei. My App is for a single tenant and requires read-write access to all SharePoint site collections. I see the following message when i debug:  "This application requires application permissions to another application. Consent for application permissions can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators."  Since the application is currently running locally it would be easier if the admin can give consent to application directly in the Azure AD portal. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: There is not. You need to construct an admin consent request, and have an admin execute it in their browser.

Comment: @Mahesh What's the REST API were you developing? Were you developing with [OneDrive API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog)(Office365 Files)? Based on my understanding, there is no such way we can give the consent on the Azure portal at present. The consent framework is working when the users fist sign-in as the link mentioned in the post.

Comment: I was developing apps to consume SP Online sites. Few of the apps we got admin consent and other apps were converted to use SharePoint Add-In only technique where we register the app at the site collection level and use client id and secret to access data. Thanks everybody for your help.